# Xrandr doesn't see display, but it works

Tags: ubuntu, xrandr, display, i3

I used to restart my workstation (Ubuntu 16.04 on board) very rarely, maybe once per few months. Yesterday, my two displays were replaced with a new ones via hot plug method. Thus, they were connected to the same ports (one - VGA, second - HDMI) and everything looked good. Today I noticed few strange things - context menu called on "primary" display is shown on another display. Then I took a look at xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
```

Where is my VGA display? It was marked "DP-2" before, thus I added before displays replacement in my i3 config (yes, I use i3wm) next lines:

```
exec xrandr --output DP-2 --auto --left-of HDMI-1
exec xrandr --output DP-2 --primary
```

I reloaded i3 config - nothing changes. I don't want to restart my workstation, open again all windows, boot VMs, etc. If there is no solution, I'll do it of course, but later. And what if it wouldn't help?

**UPDATE 1:**
After rebooting this VGA display is absent at all and now works only one display. Please, help.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Our support fixed it by plugging it via HDMI, but I'm still wondering if it was possible to fix it somehow via software.

Comment: Configurations lines starting with the `exec` setting are not run, when `i3` is restarted, only when a fresh session is started. You could use `exec_always` instead but in this case I would suggest just running the commands from a terminal.

Comment: Ok, suppose it is true. Where is my second display and how it works now?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. Depending on your setup, drivers and configuration it might be, that the *RandR* extension is not even really used and so `xrandr` just cannot show things how they really are. If you have a nVidia graphics card and user the proprietary drivers, the tool `nvidia-settings` might be able to show more accurate information. In any case, adding information about your setup (distribution, graphics card, drivers, X11 configuration, etc.) may help tracking the issue down.